# configure Intel integrated graphics in thinkpad to drive external 4k display only, via HDMI, using xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

Using the interactive displays configuration tool from the Ubuntu desktop, I have successfully configured this Thinkpad X1 Carbon (2014) with its integrated Intel video to drive an external display at 3840x2160 via the HDMI port, and not to use the display built in to the laptop.  This is the configuration I want for this workstation.

I don't use the Ubuntu desktop for every day work; rather, I use fvwm (still on Ubuntu, just not the Ubuntu desktop).  Unfortunately, it appears that the configuration utility does not change the settings in a general way, for example using some generic X mechanism, so that they work with every window manager / desktop environment.  When I log in with fvwm, both displays are in use (and the signal sent to the external one is 4096 pixels wide, not 3840).  When I log in with Ubuntu desktop, the correct, single-display, 3840px configuration takes effect.

The configuration tool appears to have written changes to some xml file in ~/.config/monitors.xml.

I need to make the configuration change so that it is both system-wide, and window-manager-agnostic.  In other words, I would like to be able to configure it via xorg.conf.

I don't know how I should specify the output used.  I have identified the output as being named "HDMI2", by looking in Xorg.0.log.  How do I work this in to xorg.conf?

Answer (score 0):

I use awesome wm (like fvwm, but for more handsome users), and I do this via xrandr. Try:

```
xrandr --output $laptop_display --off --output $external_monitor --auto
```

In my case, the displays are eDP1 and HDMI2. You can dump out the values for your system by running `xrandr` without arguments.